# How to extract value from tuple of tuples

Tags: python, logic

I have list of this sort. It is the order list of a person:

```
orderList  = [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]
#Here the second value is the quantity of the fruit to be purchased
```

How do I extract the string and the float value separately?
I need to calculate the total order cost based on the given fruit prices:

```
fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
              'limes':0.75, 'strawberries':1.00}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    """
        orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples

    Returns cost of order
    """
    totalCost = 0.0
    length = len(orderList)
    for i in range(0,length):
        for j in range(0, length - i - 1):
            totalCost += fruitPrices[orderList[i]] * orderList[j]
    return totalCost
```

This yields wrong answer. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use *unpacking* together with `for` loop to get easy to read code, for example

```
orderList  = [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]
fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
              'limes':0.75, 'strawberries':1.00}
total = 0.0
for name, qty in orderList:
    total += qty * fruitPrices[name]
print(total)  # 12.25
```

Note `,` inside `for`...`in` so `name` values become 1st element of tuple and `qty` becomes 2nd element of tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate the list of tuple, and multiply each quantity with their price and pass the iterator to `sum` function to get total

```py
total = sum(qty*fruitPrices.get(itm,0) for itm,qty in orderList)
# 12.25
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
orderList  = [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]

fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
              'limes':0.75, 'strawberries':1.00}

order_total = 0.00
```

You can iterate over the list of tuples and use `name` to get the fruit name and `quantity` to get the quantity.  Using that you can look up the price value of the fruit from the fruitPrices dictionary using the key and multiple by the quantity, totalling as you go:

```
for name, quantity in orderList:
    order_total += fruitPrices.get(name, 0) * quantity

print(order_total)
```

Then into your function would look like this:

```
orderList  = [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]

fruitPrices = {'apples':2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
              'limes':0.75, 'strawberries':1.00}

def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    """
        orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples

    Returns cost of order
    """
    totalCost = 0.0
    for name, quantity in orderList:
        totalCost += fruitPrices.get(name, 0) * quantity
    return totalCost

print(buyLotsOfFruit(orderList))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList, fruitPrices):
    totalCost = 0.0
    for order in orderList:
        item, quantity = order
        item_price = fruitPrices[item]
        totalCost += (item_price * quantity)
    return totalCost
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
order_list  = [('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]
fruit_prices = {'apples': 2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75, 'limes': 0.75, 'strawberries': 1.00}


def buyLotsOfFruit(order_list, fruit_prices):
    total_cost = 0
    for i in order_list:
        total_cost += fruit_prices[i[0]] * i[1]
    return total_cost


print(buyLotsOfFruit(order_list, fruit_prices))
```

Output:

```
12.25
```

Okay, so here is some explanation.

1. Instead of getting the length of list we can just pass it and python will iterate over it's elements automaticly.
   `for i in order_list:`
2. `i` is the current tuple in order_list eg:`[('apples', 2.0)`. So we can access it this way: `i[0]`, we get `apples`. And we use string `apples` to access apples price, you can imagine it this way: `fruit_prices["apples"]`, and so we have price.
3. We get the amount we want, we use `i[1]` which returns `2.0` in our exmaple with apples.

So you can image it looking like this:

```
total_cost += price * amount
```

And also we could do

```
total_cost = total_cost + price * amount
```

but you can also use `+=` operator to simplify the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def buyLotsOfFruit(orderList):
    """
        orderList: List of (fruit, numPounds) tuples

    Returns cost of order
    """
    fruitPrices = {'apples': 2.00, 'oranges': 1.50, 'pears': 1.75,
                   'limes': 0.75, 'strawberries': 1.00}

    totalCost = 0.0

    for item in orderList:
        fruit, price = item[0], item[1]
        totalCost += price

    return totalCost


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(buyLotsOfFruit(orderList=[('apples', 2.0), ('pears', 3.0), ('limes', 4.0)]))  # 9.0
```